# How to use gdx-pay-android-googlebilling?

Tags: android, libgdx, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement **In-App Purchase** to enable user to remove ads from my **Android app** which is developed using **Libgdx** platform, but until now I have not found a single reference which provides clear instructions to do so.

I think gdx-pay-android-googlebilling implementation (link provided below) is best suited to do so, which provides class **PurchaseManagerGoogleBilling()**.

https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/tree/master/gdx-pay-android-googlebilling

But I am having difficult time understanding it's usage as the implementation tutorial just provides one liner which says

*Add this to your AndroidLauncher's onCreate method:*

*game.purchaseManager = new PurchaseManagerGoogleBilling(this);*

Where to find a tutorial which would give clear idea about actions to perform before/after instantiation of PurchaseManagerGoogleBilling() class.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The general information how to use gdx-pay is provided in the main readme: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/blob/master/README.md#usage